# How do you Steam "in home streaming" Adobe Lightroom 4?

Tags: remote-desktop

For some reason, clicks and keystrokes don't seem to be picked up by Adobe Lightroom when streaming. Works fine with vnc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Lightroom requires admin privileges, the host machine must launch steam as an Admin (via right-click on steam). Then you can use Hamachi (for remote) or just steam stream locally Lightroom